# Distributive lattice is finite iff has finite join-irreducibles?

Tags: lattice-orders

This is exercise 4.19 in Davey and Priestley, Introduction to lattices and order, 2nd ed.

Show that, for a distributive lattice $L$ the following are equivalent:

(1) $L$ is finite;
(2) $L$ has finite length;
(3) The set $J(L)$ of join-irreducible elements of $L$ is finite.

I can prove (and I did it) that (1) and (2) are equivalent and each implies (3), but (3) doesn't seem to imply the others.
For example, the lattice $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with the order of the direct product, where each factor has the usual order, is infinite and distributive, but it doesn't have join-irreducibles, and so $J(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$, which is finite.

Is my thinking about this right?

Comment: The exercise is wrong. The book contains a hint to help prove (3)$\Rightarrow$(1) which says 'For (iii) ⇒ (i), appeal to Theorem 2.46(iii)'. This does not help, since Theorem 2.46(iii) is a statement that only has content for lattices with no infinite chains.

Comment: Your counter-example is correct. A minimal one seems to be the direct product of two chains without bottom element, such as $\mathbb Z_{<0}\times\mathbb Z_{<0}$.